# Render different asciidoc files on same webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, backend, asciidoc

I have a lot of .asciidoc files (~50). Basically, I want to create a website that can show the content of all these files on the webpage.

Till now, everything that I found basically converts the .asciidoc file into an individual .html file. This means I'll have ~50 .html files which I don't really want to do.

Is there anyway so that I can have a single webpage and somehow insert the contents of the .asciidoc file in the backend? Like PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this can be done, but not by asciidoctor itself. Take a look at the [OpenDevise landing page](https://github.com/opendevise/opendevise.io/blob/master/source/index.html.slim). You can see they're loading the files through the Asciidoctor API. You could do the same thing with shelling out or using the JavaScript port (asciidoctorjs). The main idea is to have something else generating a scaffold or template and then calling out to asciidoctor somehow to get the content.